# The color dilemma

Tags: colors, byte, bit

Let's say I have a brightest to darkest computer green colors, which is 255 possible combinations of green color, and if I pick the exact color of green, it would be stored in 1 byte. 1 byte = 8 bits. And 1 byte has 256 combinations. 256 - 255 = 1. Where does that 1 go?

Comment: For an unsigned integer in 8 bits, the values are 1 to 255 _and 0_. 256 values, the largest of which is 255.

Comment: Assuming a 8-bit per channel display. Do no assume it is so, nor it will be so forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 256 possible combinations of green color (from 0 to 255, that's 256 possibilities).

Comment: Oh so 0 counts toooo

Comment: Yeah 0 counts too! (if it helped you could you accept my answer, I still can't comment on posts...)